# How to Hide all application except map application?

Tags: ios, operating-system, system

I want restrict all the application except apple/google map application. this application is for driving related so. i want to hide all the application in iOS device. please suggest me how this is possible.

Comment: This is not possible

Answer (score 1):

Check this link [Parental Controls](https://www.apple.com/uk/newsroom/2018/06/ios-12-introduces-new-features-to-reduce-interruptions-and-manage-screen-time/)

And there are some third party tools you can search for in google. Search for "parental control ios"